# How to change child item in dojo treegrid when expended by default?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I find the child items can not be changed when I use dojox/grid/TreeGrid expanded by default,I want to select one child item to allow or deny,but its parent item
will be changed,how to prevent it,let child item can be changed respectively?

I find the function works fine under dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid,but LazyTreeGrid can not expanded by default,can we make it by default?

code Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/qqvrsgon/3/)!`Dojo treegrid`

Comment: This is the LayzyTreegrid,the check function works fine,but it can not expanded all by default. http://jsfiddle.net/qqvrsgon/4/

Comment: Not sure if I understand your needs, but if you want to change checkboxes individually your index has to be unique. You could add a timestamp or something like: `input += ' onclick="accessControl(this,' + index + new Date() + ',\''+gridId+'\')"';`. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqvrsgon/5/

Comment: Hi Guy,
my needs are:
1.The treegrid should expend all by default;
2.When check the parent item as "Allow"or "Deny" then all the children should be "Allow" or "Deny";But each child can be checked as "Allow" or "Deny" seperately;
3.For each item Allow/Deny are exclusive,you can only check 1 checkbox.
I have finished the item 2 and 3 using Dojo LazyTreeGrid,but I can not finish the item 1.(pls see my code above)
I tried to add defaultOpen:true,but it doesn't work
Then I tried to use TreeGrid but I find the formatter function doesn't work well.
How can finish them using TreeGrid or LazyTreeGrid?

Comment: If LazyTreeGrid can be expanded all by default then all the 3 requirements works perfact,but defaultOpen option doesn't work,can we do some customization to expand the LazyTreeGrid?